# How to add a subtotal row to existing data in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

[image: sample snip here]

Can anyone help me add a subtotal row to existing data in power bi. Please see the sample output on the above snip.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Adding subtotals to the source data defeats the main use of Power BI - that what it does very effectively. Instead, unpivot your data, and then write DAX measures to make desired calculations.

Comment: Do it the same way as you would a Totals row, but as an aggregation in Table.Group.  But consider @RADO comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add a subtotal to your matrix visualization in the report itself, you should use the paintbrush or customization icon on the frontend instead. There you're able to toggle subtotals and grand totals for both rows and columns. However, if it's important to have your backend data display the subtotal row, you can use M code in Power Query to "groupby" a column and summarize your data. See these links for sample code that have different techniques:

1. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1891afde-7392-4d27-b920-dfd579837dc8/how-to-add-subtotal-in-a-row-in-power-query?forum=powerquery
2. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Calculate-Subtotals-based-on-column-value-in-Power-Query-M/td-p/791788